# Node connect-flash not working on redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connect-flash

going through /temp gives flash message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GYOF.jpg)

but whenever i try to use functions from listRouter flash is not working

```
const flash=require("connect-flash");
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({secret:"secretcode", resave : false, saveUninitialized:true}));
app.use(flash());

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.locals.successMsg=req.flash("success");
    res.locals.errorMsg=req.flash("error");
    next();
})

app.get("/temp",(req,res)=>{
    req.flash("error","Error");
    req.flash("success","Success");
    console.log(res.locals);
    res.redirect("/listings");
})

app.use("/listings/:id/review",reviewRouter);
app.use("/listings",listRouter);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.